# How to get the last index from a String in a for loop

Tags: java, string

I am trying to make a program which checks if input String is palindrome. I finally managed to do it converting it to char array first, but I couldn't figure out how to access the last index from the String in for loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isPalindrome = true;

        System.out.println("Please, enter string!");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {            
            if(chars[i]!= chars[chars.length-i-1]){
                isPalindrome = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPalindrome){
            System.out.println("It is palindrome!");
        }
        if(!isPalindrome){
            System.out.println("It isnt a palindrome!");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the final result it it looks like it is working, but eclipse returns errors if I try something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        if(str.charAt(i)!= str.charAt(str.length(-1-i)){
            isPalindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

It is working if i put `-1-i` outside the the braces `(str.charAt(i)!= str.charAt(str.length()-1-i))`, but why on the first index it lets me put `i` in the braces and for the last index I can't use `i` and `-1` inside braces ?

Comment: I think you are getting confused between accessing elements in the array and calling the length method. `chars[chars.length-i-1])` is not the same as `str.length(-1-i)`. There is a large difference between `[]` and `()`. Also, if your code produces an error _show it to us_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `length()` method doesn't take any parameters.
It's the `charAt(...)` method that takes an index parameter.

And btw it's enough to go until the middle of the input string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() / 2; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(str.length() -i - 1)) {
        isPalindrome = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.length(-1-i)` is not a correct syntax, `str.length()` API doesn't accept any arguments and it's sole purpose is to give you the length of the given string.